# Excel 2019 always opens file from local network drive as write protected

Tags: microsoft-excel

### Problem

I've run into the following issue when opening an `Excel` file from a local area network drive (provided by my Synology NAS) - whenever I open the file, it is opened as `write protected` (*schreibgeschützt* in German).

[image: Excel file opens as write protected]

#### Attributes

Looking at the file's attributes, it is clearly visible that the file is **not** write protected:

[image: Excel file properties]

I can also save the file on the same network drive under a new name without any problems. When I open that new copy of the file, same behaviour as above.

#### Registry Key

I also know about some issues with older versions of Office that suggest creating a new registry key `DisableRobustifiedUNC` under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options` and setting it to `1`. As I'm using Office 2019, there's no such registry path (and still trying to set it under the 2016 path doesn't change anything).

#### Excel Trust Center

Next thing I tried was to add the network drive in Excel under the "trusted locations" (if that's the correct term for an English Excel):

[image: Excel Trust Center]

Unfortunately, same behaviour as before.

Lastly I tried - also in the Trust Center options - to completely uncheck all the settings under "protected view" (only as a temporary measure):

[image: Excel Trust Center protected view]

As before, and you may have guessed it, no change at all.

What's wrong here? How can I get Excel to open my own Excel file from my own network drive without the protected view?

### Update with animated GIF showing the behaviour

[image: Animated GIF showing the behaviour in Excel]

Comment: (1) Do you open the file from Explorer, or from Excel *File > Open*? (2) Was it a file that you opened already once since boot (sleep doesn't count)? (3) Does it happen if the antivirus is disabled?

Comment: @harrymc This is interesting - When I open the file from Explorer, the behaviour is as described in my question. When I open it via File -> Open within Excel, it opens "normally", i.e. without any write protection issues. So this is a viable workaround, though I still don't know why there is a difference in the two ways of opening the file.

Comment: if you have same problem with other file types, it might be a setting in the networkdrive. Like you have in a cloud when giving the permission "Read only".

Comment: @WeAreOne it's not a permission problem (as described above)

Comment: Do your files include the macro?

Comment: @Emily no, happens when a create a new file on the network drive from scratch, too.

Comment: @Gorgsenegger 1) Does the problem also happen with Word files? 2) Have you tried repairing the installation of Office? 3) If you create a new user on the Windows machine, does it work properly for that account?

Comment: @AndrewMorton 1) Just with Excel 2) Tried, to no avail 3) No problems with a different user

Further investigation: See my answer (I'll post it in a minute)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After unsuccessfully trying the different suggestions regarding my question, I found out that the behaviour was caused by an add-in that I'd previously installed (and later uninstalled): `AlphaVantage.excelDataAddin.xll`.

The uninstall apparently wasn't 100% successful and the add-in was still listed in `Excel` under `Options` -> `Add-Ins` -> `Active Add-Ins`. When I removed the entry (at the bottom of the `Excel Options` window, `Manage Excel-Add-Ins` -> `Go`), the behaviour was back to normal.

Comment: You might want to let AlphaVantage know about the problem: there's an email contact address on the [installation page](https://www.alphavantage.co/spreadsheets/).

Comment: @AndrewMorton good point, will do, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The fact that this only happens when opening the file from Explorer,
but not when opening from Excel with menu *File > Open*,
probably means an error in the file-association of `.xlsx` files
(or `.xls` files).

To verify :

- Run `regedit`
- Navigate to the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlsx` (similarly for `.xlsx`)
- Examine the value in the `(Default)` item, which might be for example
  `Excel.Sheet.12`
- Now use it to navigate to the key
  `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.12\shell\Open\command`
- My own command in the `(Default)` item is :

  ```
  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" "%1"
  ```
- Verify that your command is the same or similar
  (`Office16` may differ for other Office versions).
- Correct it if it's different.

This change should have an immediate effect, but if not, then
reboot might be required.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested answer. I just checked the associations in the registry and (unfortunately) I've got the same contents as in your example (see [imgur](https://imgur.com/GdhH0tf)), but the weird behaviour nonetheless.